# Submitting jsp form to servlet generates blank output

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to send a mail from a jsp form containing a text box and submit button. When user enters the email id in the text box and clicks on submit button the servlet page is called. Here the url gets changed to servlet url and the it generates blank page and mail wouldn't get send.

Here is my **demo1.jsp**

```
    <%-- 
    Document   : demo1
    Created on : 14 Sep, 2014, 10:08:26 AM
    Author     : KuNaL-IT
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%--<%@page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,javax.mail.*,java.util.Properties"  %>
<%@page import="javax.mail.internet.*,javax.activation.*" %>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>--%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form method="post" action="/BloodDirectory/mail_servlet">
                Mail id: <input type="text" name="txtmail">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My Servlet file **mail_servlet.java**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author KuNaL-IT
 */
public class mail_servlet extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, Exception {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

            mail.sendMail(request.getParameter("txtmail"));
            out.println(request.getParameter("txtmail"));
            response.sendRedirect("demo1.jsp");
//out.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            out.println("error in mail"+e);
        }
        finally
        {
            out.close();
        }

    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(mail_servlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);            
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(mail_servlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

```
And sendmail method is defined in <b>mail.java</b>
<code>
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package test;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

/**
 *
 * @author KuNaL-IT
 */
public class mail {

    public static void sendMail(String e_mail) throws Exception {
        String sender = "kunal.k.kakkad@gmail.com";
        String pass = "abcdefghijkl";
        String rec = e_mail;
        String msg = "Hello This is sample test mail...";
        String sub = "Test Subject";
        // System.out.println(rec);
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
        props.put("mail.smtps.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
        // props.put("mail.smtps.quitwait", "false");
        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        mailSession.setDebug(true);
        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        message.setSubject(sub);
        message.setContent(msg, "text/plain");
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(rec));
        transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", 465, sender, pass);
        transport.sendMessage(message,
                message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
        System.out.println(" message send");
        transport.close();
    }

}
```

I had imported mail.jar, activation.jar libraries.
Now please guide me where i am making mistake?
Please help me to send mail through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code using gmail server

public static void sendMail(String uEmail) throws Exception {
        Properties properties=new Properties();

```
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,  
               new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
               protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
               return new PasswordAuthentication("yourEmail","yourpassword");//change accordingly  
               }  
              });

    MimeMessage message=new MimeMessage(session);
    try {
        InternetAddress headers=new InternetAddress();
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("youremail"));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(uEmail));
        message.setSubject("Welcome \n your email:"+uEmail);


        message.setText(html, "UTF-8", "html");

        Transport.send(message);
System.out.println("msg success ");
    } catch (AddressException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: using gmail server means using gmail account?

Comment: yes ,yourEmail and password > return new PasswordAuthentication("yourEmail","yourpassword");//change accordingly here also   message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("youremail"));

Comment: I have to change at three places right?
1) yourEmail 2) yourpassword 3) youremail

Answer (score 0):

Make up your mind whether you want to write to the response in the servlet or redirect to a jsp...you can't do both.

I.e. Do the setting of headers and writing to out only if sending the mail failed.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, Exception
{
    try
    {
        mail.sendMail(request.getParameter("txtmail"));
        response.sendRedirect("demo1.jsp");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {   
        try 
        {
          PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
          response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
           out.println(request.getParameter("txtmail"));
           out.println("error in mail"+e);
        }
        catch(Exception ew) { /* error writing to out */ }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually i was trying either of it and just forget to remove or comment one code.
And my main focus is on sending mail no matter whether it redirects or display some messsage.

Comment: @kunalkakkad, I see you tried it both ways, but once you started writing to response and setting headers, etc. you made it impossible to redirect. See my update to my answer.

Comment: ok so whether changing the code as per you did, solves my issue?

Comment: @kunalkakkad, It might not fix whatever the issue is with sending the mail, but you shouldn't get the blank page anymore.

Comment: @kunalkakkad, you compiled, restarted the application (or Tomcat server)? Maybe you also need to clear cache.